# Routing not working AngularJS, just adding a hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I started out with AngularJS and I think it is amazing if you finally will master it, but for now I am really frustrated. I am trying to use routing. Everything works fine and there are no errors in the console, but Angular does not inject any content in my HTML :(. I am testing this on a localhost and the only thing angular does is adding a hash, like this: myAngularfolder/#/

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="app">

<head>

    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Verhaals</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="info.html">Info</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

    <div id="container" ng-view="">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
  angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])

  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
              templateURL: '/partials/products.html'
          })


  });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
templateURL: '/partials/products.html'
```

to

```
templateUrl: '/partials/products.html'
```

Comment: Yup this worked. Pff, how did I miss that? I like to write my code myself instead of copy pasting it from others so that I learn it the hard way and eventually better. I stil have to get used how angular works and how the syntax is written but I am on my way!

Comment: You are right, typing manually is more effective for remembering. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand one thing: Why did it not give me an error in the console?

Comment: Because according to source code Angular just tolerate this, it just won't do anything if there is no template or templateUrl property defined (so no content for `ngView` directive).